# Converting user input string into a valid file name

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsstring, nsfilemanager

What are the special considerations that need to be taken into account when converting a user input string into a valid file name on iOS? Are there any methods available that can help? I couldn't find anything obvious on `NSString` or `NSFileManager`.

The context is allowing users to save searches within the app. Behind the scenes, these names are converted into the names of Core Data persistent stores. The actual file names are never exposed to the user.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the file is only for iOS, about the only invalid character is the slash (`/`).

Comment: @maddy `nul` (`'\0'`)is forbidden, too.

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe Yes it is. But the question is about characters a user can type into the app. I've never seen the `nul` character on the iOS keyboard. :)

Comment: If we knew what these filenames were for, it would help us provide better answers targeted at your specific scenario.

Comment: @rmaddy Never forget about pasting. If you allow user input make sure it's sanitized properly.

Comment: @HackyStack Thanks - I've edited my question now to provide more context.

Comment: I have updated my answer to reflect your clarification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The primary concern should be the user experience: The user can type anything to identify the file. When coming back to the data she would expect to see exactly the same string she typed in.

The best way to handle this information is to store the actual input somewhere else and use a mapping to get to the actual file.

You could just use a dictionary saved in a plist file. The dictionary would contain the user input as key and a UUID as value. The file is then saved using the UUID as a file name. This way you are sure that the filename is always valid and the user can type whatever she wants without fear for invalid filenames.

An advantage over just stripping invalid characters is that the user can use for instance "/" and "//" as valid identifiers if she feels like it.

Answer (score 0):

Replace illegal characters. Something like this:

```
filename = [[filename componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]] componentsJoinedByString:@"" ];
filename = [[filename componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet illegalCharacterSet]] componentsJoinedByString:@"" ];
filename = [[filename componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet symbolCharacterSet]] componentsJoinedByString:@"" ];
fileURLString = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename];
fileURL = [NSURL URLWithString:fileURLString];
```

Check if file exists. Something like this:

```
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[fileURL absoluteString]]
```

Comment: Whitespace is allowed in filenames. A user can't type in any characters from `illegalCharacterSet`. And many symbols are allowed.

Comment: Just removing unwanted characters bears the danger of unintentionally accessing the wrong file. The user expects "foo ... bar" to be different from "foobar", yet in your code they identify the same file.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just saving searches, you shouldn't need files or filenames.  There are several ways to do this, but why not just use Core Data to save the searches as well?  You could have a "Search" entity and store all the relevant information there.

No need for files, and you are obviously already up to speed on using core data, so just use it here too.

Comment: Why limit filenames to lowercase a-z? What about users using languages that use a different alphabet (Japanese, Russian, Greek, etc.)? If the file stays on the device, there are very few symbols that the user can type that shouldn't be part of the filename.

Comment: I didn't mean only lowercase, but it should be whatever he deems a reasonable filename character.  I will edit, I obviously didn't intend to exclude upper case letters.  The point was, I personally wouldn't allow special characters whether they are valid for filenames or not.

Comment: You need to explain your reasoning for why the filename should be so restricted. I have an app that allows virtually every Unicode character a user can type on the iOS keyboard and those files work just fine.

Comment: No, I don't need to explain it, it's my opinion and recommendation, but for example, what happens when this file makes it to another operating system that may or may not support certain special characters?  Do you really need a '<' in your filename?  Finally, I told the asker of the question to decide for themselves what reasonable characters are... I told him that almost all characters are valid, and my recommendation would be not to deal with them.

Comment: This is a perfectly valid and practical solution.  I don't understand the downvotes.

Comment: I have revised my answer in light of the clarification of the question.

Comment: @HackyStack Thanks. I will be using Core Data to save the searches, but for reasons too complicated to go into here, each search will have its own SQLite file on disk. I was just looking for an elegant way to derive the database file name. I think I'm going to go with the UUID approach outlined by Nikolai. That was something I was considering anyway. I just thought that by having the file name resemble the saved search name it would make my development and debugging slightly easier.